# Sending and Receiving From a Server Simultaneously

Tags: c++, sockets

The way my code is currently written only allows a message from the server to be read directly after input is taken and a message is sent. However, this code is for a chat server and must allow a read to occur at any time a message is sent.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define SERVER_ADDRESS "127.0.0.1"
constexpr int server_port = 15555;

#define SERVER_SUCCESS "1"
#define SERVER_FAILURE "-1"

constexpr int msg_buffer_size = 4096;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    int sock;

    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "Socket creation failed!" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(server_port);

    if (inet_pton(AF_INET, SERVER_ADDRESS, &serv_addr.sin_addr) <= 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "Invalid server address!" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to connect to chat server!" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    int valread;

    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << ">> ";

        char msg[msg_buffer_size];
        char return_msg[msg_buffer_size];

        std::string input;
        std::getline(std::cin, input);

        if (input == "quit")
            return 0;

        if (input.length() > 4000)
        {
            std::cout << "Input length must be less than 4000 characters." << std::endl;
            continue;
        }

        strcpy(msg, input.c_str());
        if (send(sock, msg, strlen(msg), 0) < 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Error sending data." << std::endl;
            continue;
        }

        if (recv(sock, return_msg, msg_buffer_size, 0) < 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Error receiving data." << std::endl;
            continue;
        }

        std::string code(strtok(return_msg, " "));
        if (code == SERVER_FAILURE)
            std::cout << "Failure: " << strtok(NULL, "") << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << strtok(NULL, "") << std::endl;

        memset(msg, 0, msg_buffer_size);
        memset(return_msg, 0, msg_buffer_size);
    }

    std::cout << "Exiting." << std::endl;
    close(sock);

    return 0;
}
```

What would be a correct way to allow the client to receive a message as soon as one is sent from the server? I was thinking about making a thread, but it seemed kind of redundant since I would be receiving in two places.

Comment: I was not aware of either of these system calls. This is the first time I have worked with sockets in C++. Thank you for the suggestion, I will look into these.

Comment: Also look into threads.

Comment: Threads are interesting, but shouldn't be used in a thread-per-connection model (unless it's a toy project, or something from the 80s). On linux see `epoll` and on BSD see `kqueue` - both perform significantly better under higher loads. I didn't program Windows / Solaris, but they both have something called completion ports, which would fit higher loads.